# PowerShell import self-signed cert from keyvault

Tags: powershell, certificate, azure-powershell

I am trying to download selfsigned cert from keyvault and import it to my key store but I am failing.

```
$pfxSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $certificateName -AsPlainText

# Write to a file
Set-Content -Path $certificateFilePath -Value $pfxSecret

Import-Certificate -FilePath $certificateFilePath -CertStoreLocation 'Cert:\CurrentUser\My'
```

`$pfxSecret` looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
whatever
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
whatever
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Import-Certificate : Cannot find the requested object. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80092009)
At line:5 char:1
+ Import-Certificate -FilePath $certificateFilePath -CertStoreLocation  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Certificate], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.ImportCertificateCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

**To download self-signed certificate from key vault and import it to the key store, check the below:**

I have few certificates in key vault.

[image]

> **Note** that: To import the **pfx** certificates you need to make use of **`Import-PfxCertificate`** command.

**To import it to the key store**, I used the below commands:

```
Connect-AzAccount

$pfxSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName kvruk33 -Name rukcert33 -AsPlainText

$certificateFilePath = "C:\Users\rukmini\Desktop\rukcert33.pfx"
Set-Content -Path $certificateFilePath -Value $pfxSecret

Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certificateFilePath -CertStoreLocation 'Cert:\CurrentUser\My
```

[image]

[image]

***The certificate stored in the key store successfully:***

[image]

**Is still the issue persists,** check if you are able to certificate store:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My
```

[image]

- Validate the `$certificateFilePath` that it exists by running `Test-Path $certificateFilePath`

[image]

- Check if the certificate file is a valid PFX file.